# How to delete background color when mouse down and move css

Tags: css

I have resizable div which crops part of webpage. When mouse move and mouse down on the titles and images appears background color as you can see in the picture bellow. Can someone help me please? how can i resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: can you post your css, it is a bit unclear what the issue is... when your mouse hovers over the div there is a background color?

Comment: for example when you mark some text and background color appears, similar thing happens when i move mouse on the text or image when i want to crop part of webpage

Answer (score 0):

Use element::selection { ... }

```
   p::selection {
    color: #000; /* text-color */
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0); /* transparant bg color */
   }
```